# JPQL to select entity based on grandchild attribute

Tags: java, jpql

I am trying to select an entity `A` that has a `B` that contains a list of `C` where the value `C.d` must match a parameter.

My entities look like this:

```
@Entity
class A {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="B")
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapsId
    private B b1;
}

@Entity
class B {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="b2", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<C> cs;
}

@Entity
class C {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="B")
    private B b2;

    private String d;
}
```

My naive approach on selecting my entity look like this:

`SELECT entity FROM A entity WHERE entity.b1.cs.d = :d`

How should the query be structured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
SELECT entity FROM A entity INNER JOIN entity.b1.cs CSList WHERE CSList.d = :d
```

Read about INNER JOIN in JPA.

http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/03/24/jpa-inner-joins/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    TypedQuery<A> query = em.createQuery("select b.a from B b inner join C c where c.d = :d",A.class);
List<A> a = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how this works? It seems to return a List<A> rather then A?

Comment: yes this will return list of objects of type A, if you are certain your result will be only one object you can use getSingleResult() instead of getResultList()